# Integrate grid and polygon of municipalities keeping the biggest municipality per cell with QGIS (or another)

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, vector-grid

I have a 9x9 grid and a polygon of municipalities of an extensive area of Brazil. My goal is to have a field indicating the biggest municipality per grid cell.

I've been trying with intercept without good results. I know there are similar [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19512/sum-area-irregular-polygons-per-grid-cell) but I can't figure it out how to handle it in QGIS.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

I was thinking that maybe with intersection and then spatial union joining with maximum but it didn't work.

I want to get the final grid with a field indicating the biggest municipality inside each grid cell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it, I couldn't take my mind off of this thing and at the office I made some time to solve this; these are the steps I took in Kosmo:

1.- Create the grid 10x10 km and concatenate Row and Column into a key field

2.- Intersect the grid with the map of municipalities the new map is called *IntGridMun*

3.- Recalculate AREA for *IntGridMun*

4.- Sort the shapefile *IntGridMun* using sortshp (FWTools) "sortshp IntGridMun IntGridMunAREADesc  AREA descending" this will create a new shapefile *IntGridMunAREADesc*

5.- Generate stats for *IntGridMunAREADesc* grouping by Row and Column key field and obtaining the First municipality name

6.- Join the stats table with the original grid and you should have your map

[image]

Hope this helps

Juan José Del Toro

Comment: Thank you so much @jdeltoro. I'm gonna try and write the results.

Comment: Hi @jdeltoro, please, clarify this to me: My grid has the following fields: ID, XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX. In the Calculadora option i created a new field called [KeyField] (http://sergioibarra.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/gisstackexchange-identificar-el-mayor.html) 
`CONCAT([ID],[XMIN],[XMAX],[YMIN],[YMAX])`

Is this what you are talking about? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible database solution. If you import both the municipalities and the grid polygons into Spatialite, for example, and each polygon spatial table has an "id" column, then a query like this:

```
SELECT m.municipal_id
FROM muinicpalities AS m JOIN grid AS g ON ST_Intersects(m.geometry, g.geometry)
GROUP BY g.grid_id
ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(m.geometry, g.geometry) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

should give you the id of the municipality with the largest intersection within each grid cell. Now you can use that to update the grid table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE grid ADD COLUMN municipal_id INTEGER;

UPDATE grid SET municipal_id=(
SELECT m.municipal_id
FROM municpalities AS m JOIN grid AS g ON ST_Intersects(m.geometry, g.geometry)
WHERE g.grid_id=grid.grid_id
ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(m.geometry, g.geometry) DESC LIMIT 1;
);
```

HTH

Comment: Hey @Micha, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxsi4nq5v0ac70r/intersect_grid_muni.xlsx) is my table of attributes.  I tried with Spatialite wihtout any results. I think i'm doing something wrong:

The polygon with the municipalities is:BRA_adm2
The grid polygon is:grid9x9latlon8 
The id of the municipality is: ID_2

So, would be the code like this?

`SELECT m.ID_2`
`FROM BRA_adm2 AS m JOIN grid9x9latlon8 AS g ON ST_Intersects(m.geometry, g.geometry)`
`GROUP BY g.grid_id`
`ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(m.geometry, g.geometry) DESC LIMIT 1;`


When i run i got errors
Thank

Comment: What is the id column in your grid table called? What errors do you get?

Comment: the id column of the grid is called "ID". When i ran the script i got the following message:

`SQL error: near "DESC": syntax error`

Comment: Ooops, I see I missed a closing parenthesis:  ...ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(m.geometry, g.geometry)) DESC ...

Comment: Thank you so much @Micha, the municipality with the largest intersection within each grid cell is ID_2 = 5128
Then i ran
`ALTER TABLE grid9x9latlon8 ADD COLUMN ID_2 INTEGER;`
It was ok, and then:
`UPDATE grid9x9latlon8 SET ID_2=(
SELECT m.ID_2
FROM BRA_adm2 AS m JOIN grid9x9latlon8 AS g ON ST_Intersects(m.geometry, g.geometry)
WHERE g.ID=g.ID
ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(m.geometry, g.geometry)) DESC LIMIT 1
);`

And now i'm waiting for the results, is it the code fine?
I'm sorry for my basics questions, I'm new in spatialite and SQL programming. The good thing is that I'm gonna study it

Comment: the result was `SQL query returned an empty ResultSet
This is not an error`

I think i have an error, but i dont know where

Comment: The WHERE part of the UPDATE should be: "g.ID = grid9x9latlon8.ID". That insures that you are updating each row in the table separately. Without that, you will UPDATE the whole table againa and again for each row in the SELECT, and at the end, you'll have all the ID_2 values the same.